# Is there a workaround to reshape data back to long format

Tags: r, tidyr

I would to reverse the reshaping from wide back to long format but am stack how I should proceed so that the values for `a1_*` be placed in `a1`. Is there a workaround this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = c("s001", "s002", "s002", "s003", "s003",
              "s004", "s005"),
  a1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "A", "B"),
  a2 = c(23, 24, 45, 23, 56, 45, 34),
  a3 = c("Primary", "Secondary", "Tertiary", "Primary",
         "Tertiary", "Secondary", "Primary"))

#---- Reshape long to wide

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% ungroup()


df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id,
              names_from = index,
              values_from = starts_with("a"))

#---- Reverse back

df_long <- df_wide %>%
  pivot_longer(!id,
    names_to = "index",
    names_prefix = "a\\d_"

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is specify that you are using the specific values on the left hand of the separator to identify unique columns (i.e. `a1`, ...) and on the right `index`.

We can use the `names_sep` argument for this, and `values_drop_na` to remove rows that weren't in the original `df`.

```r
df_wide %>%
  pivot_longer(!id,
               names_to = c(".value", "index"),
               names_sep = "_",
               values_drop_na = T)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   id    index a1       a2 a3       
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1 s001  1     A        23 Primary  
#> 2 s002  1     B        24 Secondary
#> 3 s002  2     C        45 Tertiary 
#> 4 s003  1     A        23 Primary  
#> 5 s003  2     D        56 Tertiary 
#> 6 s004  1     A        45 Secondary
#> 7 s005  1     B        34 Primary
```